# Split app into two or not?

Tags: mobile-application

Wanting to know your opinion on two-sided apps.

I'm working on a project at the moment where there will be an app which a regular user would use and an app which a business will use (Similar to what Uber does).

The apps will function in a pretty similar way with some differences between the two, so not entirely the same.

The alternative to this would have a single app but include an option to sign up as a business or regular user.

My question is, when would you do one over the other?

Thanks in advance :)